# Hosting Multi-Tenant Applicaiton on Windows Server 2012 VM

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-deployment, multi-tenant, saas

I am working on a SaaS application. Say I want to host the application aa www.dostuff.com. I need to make this a multi-tenant application and would like to host that as tenant1.dostuff.com, tenant2.dostuff.com. What I have is..

1. One Windows 2012 Server with DNS Setup and One static IP
2. Domain name bought from godaddy(dostuff.com)
3. When I did my reading realized that I have to set up DNS on my VM and do the deployment. Tried doing it but wasn't able to complete
   it.

I am unable to understand clearly how to do the deployment for this and automate it. I need to integrate this to my on-boarding process and create platform data for tenants. Please let me know if I am missing something here and how do I proceed further.

Thanks

Comment: Well, I think sub domain will work. Create sub domains under main domain and point all of them to single physical source

Comment: Thanks Piyush.. But I need to point them to individual resources.. like one for tenant 1 and one for tenant 2 etc.. My Web UI is not build for Multi Tenant yet.. only my Service and DB are built for it..

Comment: oh ok, so you can point them individually. But i think sub domain will work. You dont need to setup DNS